# Validating value of a Certain key before adding it to a c# dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, string, dictionary, generics

I am trying to implement a dictionary in such a way that It will only add in a certain value to a key if that **new value** is greater than the **currently existing value**

So the basic scenarios would be:

1. If the key is not available, it will create a new key and a value
2. If the key if available, it will check if the current value is greater than the value that is already assigned to that key and will only update if it is greater.

Before I explain the problem I am facing here is my code

```
static IDictionary<string, string> versionStack = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

```
foreach(var item in RequiredApps) 
{
    nameOfApp = item.Key;
    minimumVersionOfApp = item.Value.minVersion;

    if (versionStack.TryGetValue(nameOfApp, out minimumVersionOfApp)) 
    {
         if (Convert.ToInt32(minimumVersionOfApp) >= Convert.ToInt32(item.Value.minVersion)) 
            minimumVersionOfApp = item.Value.minVersion;
    }

    versionStack[nameOfApp] = minimumVersionOfApp;
}
```

**Note:** Kindly do not worry about the `for` loop as it works fine and gives no problem there. Just want to display only the specific code that gives me problem

Right now I have been able to fulfill the functionality to a certain level but the  problem is when the `TryGetValue` is executed it turns all my values to null.

I am using the `TryGetValue` to see if a key has a value and  if so to retrieve it.

I am stuck here right now and would appreciate if anyone can help show me what I am doing wrong.

**Edit :-**

Given that the problem I am facing is quite unclear and as suggested by Rufus L I am adding a sample dummy application with exactly the problem I am facing

Hope this helps to clear any confusion :)

```
class Program
    {

        static IDictionary<string, string> versionStack = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        static string appName;
        static string minVersion;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AddOnce();
            AddTwice();

        }

        public static void AddOnce()
        {
            appName = "app01";
            minVersion = "1.0";

            versionStack.Add(appName, minVersion);
        }

        public static void AddTwice()
        {
            string existingValue;

            appName = "app01";
            minVersion = "3.0";

            if (!versionStack.TryGetValue("app01", out existingValue) || Convert.ToInt32(existingValue) < Convert.ToInt32(minVersion))
            {
                versionStack[appName] = minVersion;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you debug and verified that the key exists in Dictionary `dependentModuleStack`? Also, you mentioned you check the value in Dictionary and update it if it matches a condition, but in the code given above, you are reading from one dictionary and updating another ? Is that the desired behavior ?

Comment: Why are you using a `string` value to store an `int`? It appears that you should define it like: `static IDictionary<string, int> versionStack = new Dictionary<string, int>();`

Comment: You first define `versionStack`, but then you never use it. Then in your code you're referencing `RequiredApps` and `dependentModuleStack`, which aren't defined, but they clearly do not use a `string` value type (it does not have a `minVersion` property). Please post sample code that can be copy/pasted (i.e. all variables are defined).

Comment: @AnuViswan I had made a mistake when I was formatting the Question and really sorry about that
Can you kindly have a loook at the edited Question please :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've shown, it looks like the problem is that you're using `minimumVersionOfApp` as the `out` parameter to the `TryGetValue` method, which will be set to `null` if `TryGetValue` fails, but then we're using it anyway.

Remember that the contract with any `out` parameter is that the method *must* assign a value to it before it returns. Typically (and specifically in this case), if `TryGetValue` returns `false`, then the `out` parameter is set to the ***default value for the type***, which is `null` for classes.

Then, after the first `if` statement, you are assigning the value to the key even when `TryGetValue` returns false, which is likely why you're getting `null` values.

Instead, only use the `out` parameter if `TryGetValue` succeeds.

Here's a sample code that does this:

```
foreach(var item in RequiredApps) 
{
    var appName = item.Key;
    string existingValue;    // Note that this should be the same type as item.Value

    // If the key doesn't exist (the first condition), 
    // or it does exist and our value is greater than the existing one (second condition)
    // then update the key with our new value
    if (!dependentModuleStack.TryGetValue(appName, out existingValue) ||
        Convert.ToInt32(existingValue) < Convert.ToInt32(item.Value.minVersion)) 
    {        
        versionStack[appName] = item.Value.minVersion;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rufus 
Thank you for the explanation and your answer but I am still not able to solve the problem 
I edited the question with a  simple dummy application with what I am trying to achieve and your suggested change
Hope you wouldn't mind to take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is not with `Dictionary.TryGetValue`, but `Convert.ToInt32`

The version number is a double, and not an integer. you should use the `Convert.ToDouble` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`

```
 if (!versionStack.TryGetValue("app01", out existingValue) || Convert.ToDouble(existingValue) < Convert.ToDouble(minVersion))
 {
     versionStack[appName] = minVersion;
 }
```